# как исправить ошибку линкера?

Tags: linux, линковка

Собираю e2fsprogs. Линкер выдает ошибку:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libsupport.a(plausible.o): in function `magic_library_available':
plausible.c:(.text+0x24): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: dumpe2fs.o: in function `print_inline_journal_information':
dumpe2fs.c:(.text+0x15f9): undefined reference to `e2p_list_journal_super'
/usr/bin/ld: dumpe2fs.o: in function `print_journal_information':
dumpe2fs.c:(.text+0x1749): undefined reference to `e2p_list_journal_super'
/usr/bin/ld: dumpe2fs.o: in function `main':
dumpe2fs.c:(.text+0x2392): undefined reference to `list_super'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Пытался нагуглить ошибку - а там буквально два коммита в гитхабе, больше ничего, вообще

И что делать-то?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правильно собирать? А вообще зачем вы это делаете? Что это за дистрибутив?

Comment: я собираю Linux From Scratch

Comment: А, ну удачи! Вам там линкер как бы намекает, что статическая линковка не даст возможности использовать плагины, а другие ошибки говорит о неверной последовательности компоновки объектных файлов (либо забыли добавить соответствующую _libXYZ.a_, либо она не в том месте в командной строке). Но скорее всего проблема исправится сама собой при переходе на динамическую линковку.